# Bottom border with the same width from text value on css

Tags: html, css

I have an issue, I am trying to add 1 px to an underlined text, but researching a lot on the web I found that the only way was adding a border and a padding bottom

But the width is longer than the word and I want that the effect is the same form a underline effect, cropped with the word width.

Here is my fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/0orb5h4s/1/

And my try to the selected underline class

```
/* Underline Issue */
.selected {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
    /* text-decoration: underline; */
    padding-bottom: 1px;
}
```

Comment: @Paulie_D Because I need to have at least 1px space between the word and the underlined line

Comment: So you want to have it underlined "at least 1 pixel underneath", but when you select the text, it should select the underlined as well?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think a `span` here is what you are looking for:

```css
.horizontal-tabs li {
  display: inline;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-left: 10px;
}
.horizontal1,
.horizontal2 {
  border-left: 1px solid #000;
}
/* Underline Issue */

.selected span {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<div class="tabs">
  <ul class="horizontal-tabs">
    <li class="horizontal0">Description</li>
    <li class="horizontal1">Product Care</li>
    <li class="horizontal2 selected"><span>Shipping Information</span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

If you are actually looking to distance the underline from the text then you previous technique still works **if** you use the `span` as mentioned before.

```css
.horizontal-tabs li {
  display: inline;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-left: 10px;
}
.horizontal1,
.horizontal2 {
  border-left: 1px solid #000;
}
/* Underline Issue */

.selected span {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
  padding-bottom: 1px;
}
```

```html
<div class="tabs">
  <ul class="horizontal-tabs">
    <li class="horizontal0">Description</li>
    <li class="horizontal1">Product Care</li>
    <li class="horizontal2 selected"><span>Shipping Information</span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you add a `span` inside your li elements you could use the border style on the span element instead. I edited your fiddle code and removed some unnecessary classes that you were using for setting the `border-left` style.

**HTML**

```
<div class="tabs">
    <ul class="horizontal-tabs">
         <li><span>Description</span></li>
         <li><span>Product Care</span></li>
         <li class="selected"><span>Shipping Information</span></li>
     </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.horizontal-tabs li {
    display: inline-block;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    border-left: 1px solid #000;
}
/* This removes the first border */
.horizontal-tabs li:first-child {
    border-left: none;
}

/* Underline Issue */
.horizontal-tabs li.selected span {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
    padding-bottom: 1px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aL2n37xb/)

Answer (score 1):

Here is an answer - https://jsfiddle.net/0orb5h4s/6/

Just added

```
.selected span {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}
```

and

```
<li class="horizontal2 selected"><span>Shipping Information</span></li>
```

and removed the bottom border from the selected li.

The border applies to the padding as well and that's why adding a span moves the border to the content inside the padding.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you add a span?

HTML

```
<div class="tabs">
    <ul class="horizontal-tabs">
        <li class="horizontal0">Description</li>
        <li class="horizontal1">Product Care</li>
        <li class="horizontal2 selected">
            <span>Shipping Information</span>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.selected span {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
}
```

You can check my solution here: https://jsfiddle.net/lordfox/0orb5h4s/4/

Hope that helps! :)

Answer (score 0):

Just style the left and right margin to `auto`:

```
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
```

or

```
margin: 0 auto;
```